# How to remove a column from a table

Tags: css, material-ui, material-table

When using [detailPanel](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/detail-panel) option a new column will be added that contains an icon button.

[image]

How can I remove this extra column ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
.MuiTableCell-paddingNone {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hello Deni, Your input is working but now the onclick is not working.                                           https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-beaver-zh3gz?file=/src/Table.jsx